# LINQ Sort Distinct with Where clause

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am looking for help with a LINQ statement; Firstly, I have a List which has two columns, these are the users account and their access level.

```
AccountID |  Access
-------------------
1374      |   4
1832      |   1
1383      |   1
1182      |   2
```

The above list is obtained from the session cache.

```
List<myUsers> users = new List<myUsers>();
users = myUsers.GetFromUserSession();
```

What I would now like to do is create a new list which contains only the list of AccountID's whose access is greater than or equal to 3. Here is where I've been playing but i can't quite work out how to include the Where statement properly. For example the intellisense doesn't let me introduce something like *x.Access*.

```
List<int> adminList = myUsers.Select(x => x.AccountID).Where(x => x >= 3).Distinct().ToList()
```

I'm now at the point where i'm just tinkering with it until something works, but thought I would ask the community as i'm sure this is something very easy for some folk to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing the `select` before the `where` you only get the `AccountID` from that point on so you apply the `where` to the `AccountID`.

it should be

```
List<int> adminList =myUsers.Where(x => x.Access >= 3).Select(x => x.AccountID).Distinct().ToList()
```

Answer (score 3):

your query is wrong structured

```
var admins = myUsers.Where(x => x.Access >= 3)
          .Select(x => x.AccountID)
          .Distinct()
          .ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use the `Where`first and then select what you want from `myUsers`(the `AccountID`):

```
List<int> adminList = myUsers
    .Where(x => x.Access >= 3)
    .Select(x => x.AccountID) // here x is still the myUsers instance
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```